# Putting links to scripts in my cygwin bin

Tags: shell, cygwin

I have made a few python scripts, but is there an easier way to run them? I am using cygwin.

```
python "C:\Users\Desk\Dropbox\scripts\wsort.py" > data11414_unsorted.txt < data11414_sorted.txt
```

I want something like this (not typing the path name or "python"):

```
wsort > data11414_unsorted.txt < data11414_sorted.txt
```

where `wsort` is a link to my real wsort.py

Answer (score 1):

Add a
[Shebang](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)
to the script

```sh
#!/bin/python
```

then invoke like this

```
wsort.py > data11414_unsorted.txt < data11414_sorted.txt
```

Comment: I edited the original question. The thing i want to get rid of is the path typing to the script. I can put it in the bin can't I?

Answer (score 1):

First, your question has a Windows-style path (backslashes, beginning with `C:`) rather than a Cygwin path (`/cygdrive/c/Users/Desk/Dropbox/scripts/wsort.py`). That implies you're not actually using Cygwin, or if you are, you're ignoring a bunch of warnings.

The below assumes you're using Cygwin Bash (which should be what you get if you start Cygwin Terminal from the Start Menu) and Cygwin Python (which you've installed using Cygwin's [setup.exe](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html), not a Windows Python installer). If your not, you're making life more difficult for yourself than you need to.

That out the way, there's a bunch of steps you need to take:

- First, make the script executable. Use the `chmod` command for that, from a Cygwin Bash shell:

  ```
  chmod +x /cygdrive/c/Users/Desk/Dropbox/scripts/wsort.py
  ```
- Second, tell the system *how* to execute it. Add the following line to the top of the script:

  ```py
  #!/bin/python
  ```

  (That's a "shebang". Python sees it as a comment, so doesn't do anything with it, but Cygwin and other Linux-like systems will use that line to see which program to run the script with. In this case, Python.)
- Third, make sure your line endings are correct. Cygwin expects Linux line endings and will fail without them. This may not be a problem, but there's no harm in doing this. Run the following command:

  ```
  dos2unix /cygdrive/c/Users/Desk/Dropbox/scripts/wsort.py
  ```

  At this point, you'll be able to call the script by specifying the full path to it in Cygwin.  You can't yet run it without specifying where the script is explicitly.
- The fourth step is making sure the script is "in your path", ie in one of the folders where Cygwin looks for scripts to run.  There are lots of ways to do this, but the most sensible is probably to just add your scripts directory to your path.  The following command will add your scripts directory to your path whenever you start a new Cygwin session:

  ```
  echo 'PATH="/cygdrive/c/Users/Desk/Dropbox/scripts:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc
  ```

  You will need to restart your Cygwin terminal for that to take effect, however.

  At that point, you'll be able to run the script in Cygwin just by typing `wsort.py` (and thus use it with redirections and so forth as in your question).
- Finally, to be able to call it simply as `wsort`, there's a number of options.  The obvious one is just renaming the file.  More usefully (and without copying the file or doing anything liable to break with Dropbox syncing things), try creating an alias:

  ```
  echo 'alias wsort=wsort.py'  >>~/.bashrc
  ```

  Again, you'll need to restart your Cygwin terminal for that to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an alias ?

```
alias wsort = "Command_Used"
```